# Closing a python DDE 'Conversation', and terminating server?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, dde

OK, DDE is ridiculously *ancient* technology, but, I'm stuck with it for the moment.

In python 2.7 I'm able to start a DDE server, and create conversations to collect data from the 3rd party application, however, I can't figure out how to gracefully terminate the conversation/server.

The DDE module is compiled (it is 'dde.pyd'), so I can't look inside

When I run 'help(dde)', after importing DDE (and win32ui), I don't see any functions for closing things down.

Can anyone offer me any help?